# External program pdflatex finished with an error on lyx

Tags: pdftex, lyx, miktex

3.6 with Miktex 20.11 (both x64 bits). I searched for updates of miktex.

My problem is that when compiling, exporting or previewing in pdf i got this error: external program pdflatex finished with an error.

I know there are more questions that talks about the same error but i've been trying to fix it for hours and i can't solve it.

In the logs file says:

2020-12-10 12:38:14,118+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (992) started by 'cmd' with command line: pdflatex archivo_nuevo1.tex
2020-12-10 12:38:14,134+0100 INFO  pdflatex - allowing known shell commands
2020-12-10 12:38:14,134+0100 INFO  pdflatex - enabling input (output) from (to) processes
2020-12-10 12:38:14,815+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Conversion from UTF-8 byte sequence to wide character string did not succeed.
2020-12-10 12:38:14,816+0100 INFO  pdflatex - this process (992) finishes with exit code 1

Thank you.

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Glad you solved the problem. Next time, please upload a minimal example file. For more information, see here: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved. I use Luatex instead of pdflatex and when errors come out I omit them, that's it.

Comment: While always consider using LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX to be the best solution for any problem :), I strongly recommend not to ignore any errors. This will only lead to harder to diagnose issues later on.

Answer (score 0):

You see, I had the same problem. But I found that this problem is related to the path, that is, the name of the folder and the file name. I am not sure, but I had the same message and after some tests the problem was solved by simply changing the folder name and the file name without special characters.

I am just trying to help you, but I am not sure.